# Переписал код с Python на c++, но где-то ошибся

Tags: c++, python, инспекция-кода, олимпиада

код на python:

```
a = int(input())
q = 0
we = 0
j = 0
if len(str(a)) == 1:
    print(a)
else:
    for i in range(10,a):
        q = i
        we = i
        s = 0
        while len(str(q)) != 1:
            for e in range(len(str(q))):
                p = int(str(q)[e])
                we += p
                s += p
            q = s
            s = 0
        if we == a:
            print(i)
            j = 1
            break
    if j != 1:
        print(-1)
```

код на c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int q;
    int we;
    int j;
    int s;
    int p;
    j = 0;
    string cv;
    string asdf;
    cin >> a;
    cv = to_string(a);
    if (cv.size() == 1)
    {
        cout << a;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 10; i < (a + 1); i++) {
            q = i;
            we = i;
            s = 0;
            asdf = to_string(i);

            while (asdf.size() != 1)
            {
                for (int e = 0; e < asdf.size(); e++)
                {
                    p = asdf[e];
                    we += p;
                    s += p;

                }

                q = s;
                s = 0;
                asdf = to_string(q);

            }
            if (we == a)
            {
                cout << i;
                j = 1;
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    if (j != 1)
    {
        cout << "-1";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста, во втором коде цикл становится бесконечным, f а такого быть не должно, как это исправить?

Comment: Прямой перевод, да еще на таких разных языках, редко бывает удачным. Не проще написать с нуля?

Comment: В данный момент проще найти ошибку, так как я знаю ее  местоположение, она в цикле while, но не понимаю, почему цикл становится бесконечным, может быть Вы найдете ошибку

Comment: Мне проще написать заново. Когда я не понимаю, что код должен делать - искать ошибки для меня - задача почти неподъемная. Лучше скажите, что ваша программа должна делать...

Comment: https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=11832&chapterid=111505

Comment: Простите, я верно понимаю, что вы работаете просто перебором всех чисел? (Извините, я сейчас вынужден уходить от компьютера, вернусь поздно - так что простите заранее, буду долго молчать...)

Comment: Да, все верно, я решаю перебором

Comment: Что делает этот таинственный код?

Comment: На вскидку, у вас `for (int i = 10; i < (a + 1); i++) {` не эквивалентно `for i in range(10,a):`, так как в питоне само значение `a` не будет обрабатываться внутри цикла, а в плюсах `a` будет обработано.

Comment: Отладка через печать значений легко вам поможет для поиска остальных несоответствий. Вы можете просто сравнить вывод переменных обоих программ

Comment: Эникейщик, я в комментарии ссылку на задачу отправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если вы так хотите перебором - т.е. пролететь по времени на реально больших тестах вас не пугает - то вот ваш код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned int sum(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n < 10) return n;
    unsigned int m = 0, s = n;
    while(s)
    {
        m += s%10;
        s /= 10;
    }
    return n + sum(m);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int B;
    cin >> B;
    for(unsigned int a = 1; a <= B; ++a)
    {
        if (sum(a) == B)
        {
            cout << a << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << -1 << endl;
}
```

А вот если подумать о возможном диапазоне и изменить перебор - то вполне можно успеть, если заменить

```
for(unsigned int a = 1; a <= B; ++a)
```

на

```
for(unsigned int a = (B > 110) ? B-110 : 1 ; a <= B; ++a)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, кстати, можно еще ускорить, заменив 110 на 102

Comment: Да, но я решил не рисковать :) - вдруг в прикидках ошибся... Разница уже совершенно небольшая.

Comment: Кстати, по вашему переводу - в нем совершенно напрасно выполняется постоянное превращение в строку, и еще - `p = asdf[e];` дает ASCII-код цифры, но не ее числовое значение (для этого надо еще вычесть `'0'` - вот тут вы циклу и не давали завершиться, получая большое число...

Comment: Понял, просто только недавно начал C++ изучать и не знал этого, еще раз спасибо